# Intern - ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

Seeing this Error message when I'm trying to run Intern tests from within my test files dir. the (relevant) structure of the dir is:

- test
- - resources
- - - rest
- - - - pickup.js
- - - - cashManagement.js
- - - gitignore
- - - intern.js
- - - packages.js
- - - packages.sample.js
- - - ...

The inter.js contains references to  *testFile1.js* and *testFile2.js* in the *suites* section. I played a bit with the way these 2 files are referenced and got a "Failed to load module..." error. So I guess now that's solved and the ReferenceError is the one I need to figure out. I did go over the existing threads and nothing seems to solve my issue. The full error message is pasted below. I'll gladly supply more relevant info if needed.

Thanks,
Eran

```
***ReferenceError: document is not defined**
    at /Applications/dojo-release-1.10.2/dojo/has.js:31:33
    at execModule (/Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:515:54)
    at /Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:504:12
    at Array.map (native)
    at execModule (/Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:499:17)
    at /Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:582:7
    at guardCheckComplete (/Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:566:4)
    at checkComplete (/Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:574:27)
    at onLoadCallback (/Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:656:7)
    at /Users/eranbrand/src/MobilePosSolution/ovc-build/ovc-repo/src/test/node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/dojo.js:761:5*
```

Here's the content of the intern.js file:

```
// Learn more about configuring this file at <https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Configuring-Intern>.
// These default settings work OK for most people. The options that *must* be changed below are the
// packages, suites, excludeInstrumentation, and (if you want functional tests) functionalSuites.

serviceURL = "http://ovc.local:8080/POSMClient/json/process/execute/";


define(['./packages'], function(Packages) {

    var returnValue = {
        // Configuration options for the module loader; any AMD configuration options supported by the specified AMD loader
        // can be used here
        loader: {
            packages: Packages.packages
        },

        // The port on which the instrumenting proxy will listen
        proxyPort: 9000,

        // A fully qualified URL to the Intern proxy
        proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/',

        // Default desired capabilities for all environments. Individual capabilities can be overridden by any of the
        // specified browser environments in the `environments` array below as well. See
        // https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities for standard Selenium capabilities and
        // https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#desired-capabilities for Sauce Labs capabilities.
        // Note that the `build` capability will be filled in with the current commit ID from the Travis CI environment
        // automatically
        capabilities: {
            'selenium-version': '2.39.0'
        },

        // Browsers to run integration testing against. Note that version numbers must be strings if used with Sauce
        // OnDemand. Options that will be permutated are browserName, version, platform, and platformVersion; any other
        // capabilities options specified for an environment will be copied as-is
        environments: [/*
         { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '11', platform: 'Windows 8.1' },
         { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '10', platform: 'Windows 8' },
         { browserName: 'internet explorer', version: '9', platform: 'Windows 7' },
         { browserName: 'firefox', version: '27', platform: [ 'OS X 10.6', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
         { browserName: 'chrome', version: '32', platform: [ 'OS X 10.6', 'Windows 7', 'Linux' ] },
         { browserName: 'safari', version: '6', platform: 'OS X 10.8' },
         { browserName: 'safari', version: '7', platform: 'OS X 10.9' }*/
        ],

        // Maximum number of simultaneous integration tests that should be executed on the remote WebDriver service
        maxConcurrency: 3,

        // Whether or not to start Sauce Connect before running tests
        useSauceConnect: false,

        // Connection information for the remote WebDriver service. If using Sauce Labs, keep your username and password
        // in the SAUCE_USERNAME and SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY environment variables unless you are sure you will NEVER be
        // publishing this configuration file somewhere
        webdriver: {
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 4444
        },

        // The desired AMD loader to use when running unit tests (client.html/client.js). Omit to use the default Dojo
        // loader
        useLoader: {
            'host-node': 'dojo/dojo',
            'host-browser': 'node_modules/dojo/dojo.js'
        },

        // Non-functional test suite(s) to run in each browser
        suites: [
            "rest/pickup",
            "rest/cashManagement"
        ],

        // Functional test suite(s) to run in each browser once non-functional tests are completed
        functionalSuites: [ /* 'myPackage/tests/functional' */ ],

        // A regular expression matching URLs to files that should not be included in code coverage analysis
        excludeInstrumentation: /^tests\//
    }

    return returnValue;
});
```

Comment: Could you also show what configuration is used?

Comment: Of course. Do you mean the intern.js file?

Comment: Added the intern.js to the original question. (the pasted JS formating is a bit messed up. It starts right after the "Here's the content of the intern.js file" line and ends after the "return returnValue;" line).

Comment: How are you running Intern? Browser client, intern-client, or intern-runner?

Comment: I'm running it from the directory using the following: ***intern-client config=intern.js***

Comment: And thanks for the formatting, Ken.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using the release build of Dojo, which assumes the `document` object will be available. To use that build you'll need to run intern with `intern-runner` or the browser client (`client.html`). If you'd prefer to run your tests with the node client (`intern-client`), you'll need to use the source distribution of Dojo or the dojo npm package.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. Do you know where I can find samples for how it's done? Thanks. EB

Comment: Some basic instructions are in the [Intern wiki](https://github.com/theintern/intern/wiki/Running-Intern). To use `intern-runner`, the easiest thing is to start a local Selenium server, set the `tunnel` option in your intern.js to 'NullTunnel', and run intern with `intern-runner` instead of `intern-client`. To use the browser client, your code must be accessible via a web server; assuming you're serving your test directory at localhost:8080, load `http://localhost:8080/node_modules/intern/client.html?config=tests/intern` in a browser.